# How to merge dictionaries in for loop - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to merge dictionaries returning from for loop. I have to then take maximum total from the dictionary. I am new to python. Please find below my code.

```
def winner(dictn):
for k,v in dictn.items():
    total = 0
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        total = total+v1
        team = {k:total}
    print(team)
winner(qualifier_2)
```

And my current output is:

```
{'KKR': 2236}
{'MI': 1759}
```

dictionary after update should look like:
    **{'KKR': 2236, 'MI':1759}**

Then it should return the team which scored maximum runs ie. winner 
Expected output:
    **KKR**

Comment: Please don't link code as an image when pasting it in your post only costs a few clicks.

Comment: `dictn[k] = total` should do the merge

Comment: And also add an example of input with expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: thank you I have updated my question with all your suggestions.

Comment: @RamanMishra no he want to merge the dictionaries from the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

if the dictonary is:

```
{
  "KKR": 1
  "MI" : 2 
}
```

you can run this code:

```
def winner(dictn):
    print(max(dictn, key=dictn.get))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the output from my code does not return as a single dictionary. Please find below my output.                                                                                                 
Actual output:                                                                                                    
{'KKR': 2226}
{'MI': 1753}                                                                                                                           Expected output: {'KKR' : 2226, 'MI', 1753 }

Comment: @Joaquim De la Cruz you are giving a reverse answer. He wants the dictionary you are placing.